# How could I print the contents of any container in a generic way?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, operator-overloading

I am trying to write a piece of code for fun using C++ templates.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class Container>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Container& container)
{
    typename Container::const_iterator beg = container.begin();

    o << "["; // 1

    while(beg != container.end())
    {
        o << " " << *beg++; // 2
    }

    o << " ]"; // 3

    return o;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> list;

    list.push_back(0);
    list.push_back(0);

    std::cout << list;

    return 0;
}
```

***The above code doesn't compile :)***

At 1, 2, 3 the same error is produced : **error C2593: 'operator <<' is ambiguous**

All what I am trying to do is overloading the << operator to work with any container. Does that make sense ? How would that be done If possible, if not why ?

EDIT :: Thanks for corrections :) 'sth' way is a good solution.

I am just curious if this ambiguity -as Neil explained- would go away if we could use C++0x Concepts ?

Comment: What compilation errors are you getting?

Comment: I'd recommend making your container argument a const reference and using const_iterator.  This avoids unnecessary copying and allows const containers to be printed.

Comment: Regarding concepts, the C++ Standards Comittee has just kicked them into the long grass - they won't be part of tyhe next standard

Comment: @Neil, do you have a pointer where I can get a look to the latest updates on the C++0x state?

Comment: I'm ashamed to say I got this http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=441 off reddit :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can restrict your operator<< to only apply to templated containers by specifying that the Container template parameter is itself templated. Since the C++ std containers also have an allocator template parameter you also have to include this as a template parameter of Container.

```
template
    < typename T
    , template<typename ELEM, typename ALLOC=std::allocator<ELEM> > class Container
    >
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const Container<T>& container)
{
    typename Container<T>::const_iterator beg = container.begin();

    o << "["; // 1

    while(beg != container.end())
    {
        o << " " << *beg++; // 2
    }

    o << " ]"; // 3

    return o;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> list;

    list.push_back(0);
    list.push_back(0);

    std::cout << list;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I still don't get it :( what information was missing for operator <<. can you please explain a little more ? how forcing it to be a template container resolved the ambiguity of operator << . in fact I want to know what ambiguity was there in first place when we used os << "["; or os << *beg++;

Comment: The `operator<<` being defined is templated for any type. This creates an ambiguity because `operator<<` is already defined for ints, chars, strings etc. So the calls to `o << "["` causes a compiler error because it doesn't know which one is being called - the original `<<` (i.e. from the std lib) or the new templated `<<`. By restricting the `operator<<` definition to only apply to templated classes we remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

Your newly defined `operator<<` does not only match containers, but also any other types like ints and strings. That's why the compiler complains about ambiguities when it needs to find the matching `operator<<` to output `"["`.

One way to work around this problem would be to rename your output function:

```
template <class Container>
std::ostream& container_out(std::ostream& o, const Container &container) {
  // ...
}
```

You can then add simple wrappers to enable `operator<<` for all the containers you want to print:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const std::vector<T> &container) {
  return container_out(o, container);
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const std::map<T> &container) {
  return container_out(o, container);
}
```

Comment: I don;t think those operater<< specializations will work, since they don't take into account the optional allocator template parameter.

Comment: And the name _out is reserved at namespace scope.

Comment: @Evan Teran: It will work for vectors that use the default allocator, for others the `operator<<` definition needs to be extended by the additional argument.

Answer (score 3):

What is the error? I saw one, you need a typename:

```
typename Container::iterator beg = container.begin();
```

What happens here is that the compiler doesn't know anything about Container when it is first reading it. So we have to give it a little help and tell it that iterator will be a type(syntactically it could be any valid name at class scope, so a function, variable,...). When writing a template method, any type that depends on the template type must specify that it is a type with the keyword `typename`.

Comment: I am not sure, but what does typename means ?

Answer (score 2):

Your operator introduces its own ambiguity - it could itself be used for printing the things it is trying to print. My advice:

- use a named function, not an operatr
- pass the container by const reference (this is nothing to do with the problem, however)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now your template it causing confusion. The compiler can't decide between your operator and the one that you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not as generic as what you are posting (you need to pass the type contained), and also leaves an extra separator at the end, but you can use the STL for this:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back( 10 );
v.push_back( 20 );

std::cout << "[";
std::copy( v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
std::cout << "]";
```

Will output:

> [10 20 ]

Note that the extra separator is at the end of the sequence and that there is no initial space between the [ and the first element.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.csdn.net/cqdjyy01234/article/details/19234329 may be a good solution. It works for STL containers and the C-style array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *constexpr* to check Datatype of containers like *Stacks,Queues* for different printing mechanism and add generic method called **PrintContainer** check the below code.

First check datatype for Stack,Queue,Map etc.

```
// Template for Checking Map.
template <class T>
struct is_map
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <class Key, class Value>
struct is_map<std::map<Key, Value>>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

// Template for Checking Stack.
template <class T>
struct is_stack
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <class T>
struct is_stack<std::stack<T>>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

// Template for Checking Queue.
template <class T>
struct is_queue
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <class T>
struct is_queue<std::queue<T>>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};
```

Then include General method for Printing Container like this.

```
template <typename T>
void PrintContainer(T container, bool showSize = false)
{
    if (showSize)
        std::cout << "Size: " << container.size() << std::endl;
    // Container for Map.
    if constexpr (is_map<T>::value)
    {
        for (const auto &[k, v] : container)
        {
            std::cout << k << "\t" << v << std::endl;
        }
    }
    // Container for Stack & Queue.
    else if constexpr (is_stack<T>::value || is_queue<T>::value)
    {
        while (!container.empty())
        {
            if constexpr (is_stack<T>::value)
                std::cout << container.top() << "\t";
            else if constexpr (is_queue<T>::value)
                std::cout << container.front() << "\t";
            container.pop();
        }
    }
    // General Container like list,set etc.
    else
    {
        for (const auto &data : container)
        {
            if constexpr (!is_map<T>::value)
                std::cout << data << "\t";
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Then call it from Main method like this.

```
int main()
{
    //Defining containers.
    std::list<int> iList({10, 20, 30, 40, 50});
    std::map<string, string> sMap{
        {"Abdul", "Java"},
        {"Mohammed", "C++"},
        {"Ahmet", "Python"}};
    std::set<int> iSet({10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 30});
    std::array<int, 5> iArray({11, 22, 33, 44, 55});
    std::stack<float> fStack({1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5});
    std::queue<float> fQueue({11.5, 22.5, 33.5, 44.5});

    //Printing data of containers.
    PrintContainer(iList);
    PrintContainer(sMap);
    PrintContainer(iSet);
    PrintContainer(iArray);
    PrintContainer(fStack);
    PrintContainer(fQueue);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10      20      30      40      50
Abdul   Java
Ahmet   Python
Mohammed        C++

10      20      30      40      50
11      22      33      44      55
4.5     3.5     2.5     1.5
11.5    22.5    33.5    44.5
```

[Full Source Code - PrintContainer.cpp](https://gist.github.com/haseeb-heaven/79e46651347155be7ae7e55a57da91c0)