# Printing Any STL Container

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++14

**How would you go about writing a library that, when included, it overloads the `<<` operator for *any** existing STL container?**

- *Except adaptors like stack and queue, since you cannot iterate through them.*

The one self-imposed requirement is that it *mustn't* include any of the containers' header files. That would bloat the final executable unnecessarily. It makes more sense to include this header after the containers' that I would like to work with. This restriction implies the use of `templates` or `macros`.

**I'm looking for advice and pointers**, so, *please*, don't just post fully working code that can do this! Implementing this myself is part of the learning process. Small snippets of code that demonstrate how certain things work are welcome.

**What I did up to this point:**

I have overloaded the `<<` operator for every container with a different *template signature*. The problem that I have run into with this approach is, that there are containers that have the same number of template parameters, but some contain `std::pair`-s, others `single values`. More precisely, this is the case of `std::map` & `std::multimap` vs `std::unordered_set` & `std::unordered_multiset`.

This collision forces me to either implement a non-template version of one of the pairs, or to come up with a way to differentiate between `std::pair`-s and `single values`. I don't really know how to go about doing the second one, though. The reason because I'm not "*how to do that*" directly is that I'm starting to believe that this could be avoided entirely with a better overall design.

*Thank you in advance!*

---

**What worked for me:**

1. Overload `operator<<` for `std::pair`
2. Overload `operator<<` for every STL container with different template arguments

   > Note:
   >
   > 1. `template <typename T1>` and `template <typename T1, typename T2>` *are* different
   > 2. `template <typename T1, typename T2>` and `template <typename T1, size_t T2>` *are*
   >      different
   > 3. `template <typename T1, typename T2>` and `template <typename C1, typename C2>`
   >      are *NOT* different
3. Put them in a namespace to make sure that your operators won't collide with any other operators that you might need in the future.

Use "templates in templates", so for example a function would look like:

```
template <typename Type, template <typename TYPE> class TClass>
void func(TClass<Type>& tc) {
    if (tc.somethingTrue())
        tc.doStuff();
}
```

Comment: This will be a heckuvalot easier to do whenever Concepts get into the standard.

Comment: For your "pair vs value" problem, you could overload `<<` for `std::pair`, then use the inner `value_type` typedef that all containers have.

Comment: Do you mean something like [cxx-prettyprint](https://louisdx.github.io/cxx-prettyprint/)? (If you don't want a ready solution but want to code it by yourself, you can get inspired by its implementation. Ask a more specific question if you don't understand some part of it.)

Comment: You could try forward declaring the different container types, and then make specific `<<` overloads for each container you care about with any possible specialization. This is a bit tedious for some of them though, e.g., for vector there are these rarely used parameters for allocators and such. If you can manage to forward declare them correctly then there's not much work after that I guess.

Comment: @ChrisBeck You mean forward declaring like a vector for every possible template argument? That is a wee bit tedious :D

Comment: @Quentin That seems like a possible solution, thanks, I'll look into it!

Comment: @leemes Thank you, I'll look into that!

Comment: @mrDudePerson you can forward-declare templates, and since the standard containers' signatures are defined by the Standard, it's just a matter of opening `namespace std` and copy-pasting them from [a documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) ;)

Comment: mrDudePerson: you could do something like this, for a generic type: `template <typename T> struct A;  template<typename T> std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & ss, const A<T> & a) { ss << "printing an a: " << a.contents; return ss; }` Once templates are involved, it doesn't matter that A hasn't been fully declared when your `<<` implementation is read, the errors can only occur when `<<` is fully instantiated and T is known. So as long as you include the full definition before trying to actually use the `<<` overload it is legit. Quentin makes a good point about how to actually go about it

Comment: @ChrisBeck That makes sense, gonna look into it right now!

Comment: @Quentin That's UB and in fact will fail on at least one implementation I know of (libc++).

Comment: @T.C. could you expand on why it is the case ? And is there another way to retrieve only the declarations of standard types ?

Comment: @Quentin [The standard bans adding declarations to `namespace std`](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#1), and it fails on libc++ because everything in libc++ is actually in an inline namespace inside `std`. The only way to get the declarations is by including the appropriate header. (Besides, if you are iterating over a container to print its contents, you *need* its definition anyway.)

Comment: @T.C. I thought that only applied to user types, not to standard types. But that failure case makes sense.

Comment: An unavoidable issue is that this operator can't be found by ADL (since you can't add it to `std`), and its name will be hidden by any other `operator<<`.  I think the best practice will be to declare your operators in their own namespace (say Foo) and require the user to have `using namespace Foo;` in scope whenever you want to enable these overloads.

Comment: @M.M That seems like a good idea. One question, though, does `nmsp::operator<<` enable all operators, and is there a way to separate them.

Comment: Minor observation: Don't confuse **override** with **overload**.  You seem to be using the two words interchangeably in your question.

Comment: @legalize Right, thanks! :) I always forget which is which. I'll correct those right away.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72651277/6219626

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could overload `operator<<` as a template that takes a template template argument (i.e., any container).

Then you could provide two overloads of a template function (e.g., `print`) that the one overload would specialize on `std::pair`.

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& print(std::ostream &out, T const &val) { 
  return (out << val << " ");
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
std::ostream& print(std::ostream &out, std::pair<T1, T2> const &val) { 
  return (out << "{" << val.first << " " << val.second << "} ");
}

template<template<typename, typename...> class TT, typename... Args>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, TT<Args...> const &cont) {
  for(auto&& elem : cont) print(out, elem);
  return out;
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfd849654caded29)

Comment: @101010 There is a flaw with this solution which is you cannot print a string. Does anyone know how to fix it? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99e5f1b0b5501e61

Comment: @grokus, this seems to work well: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d77eabef9fd5669b

Comment: @ded32 Seems to work for a single string, but not for a container of strings. See https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59e3d4954a4609b6

Answer (score 8):

A *very* simple attempt at this problem is something like:

```
template<typename T>  
void print_container(std::ostream& os, const T& container, const std::string& delimiter)  
{  
    std::copy(std::begin(container),   
              std::end(container),   
              std::ostream_iterator<typename T::value_type>(os, delimiter.c_str())); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, that combined with forward declaring the different template types might work.

Comment: It's very a crude starting point to your OP.  Don't expect any up votes, just wanted to get the ball rolling. And couldn't post all this as comment. :)

Comment: No worries every bit helps :)