# C++ functions to fill in and print arbitrary container

Tags: templates, stl

As I'm learning C++ I would like to write a couple functions to

- fill in an arbitrary container
- print values of an arbitrary container

So far I managed to write the second function one for an *arbitrary* container, but not the first function.

Print function:

```
template <class C>
void printMyContainer(C v) {
  for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
    std::cout << std::setw(3) << *it << " ";    
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Fill in function:

```
template <typename T>
using in = typename std::istream_iterator<T>;

template <class C, typename T>
C fillInMyContainer(C v) {
    std::cout << "Enter values:"<<std::endl;        
    std::for_each(in<T>(std::cin), in<T>(), 
    [&](T a) { v.push_back(a); });
    return v;
}
```

Now, the fill in function has a `push_back` method, which is not common for *all* containers.

Hence I was wondering

- how can I pass the *fill-in* function into the `fillInMyContainer` function? I tried to do something like:

  ```
  template <class C, typename T>
  C fillInMyContainer(C v, void (*f)(T)) {
    std::for_each(in<T>(std::cin), in<T>(),
    [&](T a) { (*f)(a); });
    return v;
  }
  ```
- are there already such templates?

Comment: Read up on `std::back_inserter` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72651277/6219626

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, printing (the way you do it) can be in a slightly more compact form:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template<class C> std::ostream &printContainer(std::ostream &s, C const &c) {
     std::copy(c.begin(), c.end(), std::ostream_iterator<typename C::value_type>(s, " "));
     return s;
}
```

Though it's not important. Now, for adding elements to arbitrary container you can use the marvels of SFINAE:

```
template<class C, class T>
decltype(std::declval<C>().insert(std::declval<T>()), C{}) fillContainer(C c) {
    std::for_each(in<T>(std::cin), in<T>(), [&c](T const &t){ c.insert(t); });
    return c;
}
```

Or maybe even

```
template<class C>
decltype(std::declval<C>().insert(std::declval<typename C::value_type>()), std::declval<C &>()) fillContainer(C &c) {
    using T = typename C::value_type;
    std::for_each(in<T>(std::cin), in<T>(), [&c](T const &t){ c.insert(t); });
    return c;
}
```

What lives inside the parentheses after `decltype` is a comma operator in *an unevaluated context*. Were such an expression found on its own on a separate line, the program would never be built (`std::declval` does not have definition, for instance), but merely as an expression to be checked for type-validity it's okay. So, this overload is only chosen when `c.insert(t)` compiles (and `C{}` after the comma gives us a return type for function.) For vectors (or strings), you can add another:

```
template<class C, class T>
auto fillContainer(C c) -> decltype(c.push_back(std::declval<T>()), C{});
```

(Here, I've put the SFINAEing `decltype` into a trailing return type, which in this particular case saves us one call to `std::declval`, as by this moment we already have `c` of type `C`, so we don't need to call `std::declval` to create a reference to `C`.)

Comment: may I ask for the example of  how to actually call the `fillContainer` function (the template specification in particular)?

Comment: Hmm, `std::set<int> ints; ints = fillContainer<std::set<int>, int>(ints);` But see my edit, I've added a more straightforward version of the same.

Comment: interesting, if I use the second version, replace `insert` with `push_back`, then the line `std::vector<int> v = fillVContainer<std::vector<int> >(v);` returns `v` to be of size 0; but if I do `std::vector<int> v;
  v = fillVContainer<std::vector<int> >(v);` then everything works ok...

Comment: @AlexanderShubert Try it with something like -Wall -Wpedantic.