# Is there a better way to generic print containers in C++20/C++23?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++23

I use the following code to print generic C++ containers and exclude strings (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1154683/2599610) SO answer).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T,
          template <typename ELEM, typename ALLOC = std::allocator<ELEM>>
          class Container>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Container<T> &container) {
  out << "[";
  bool first = true;
  for (const auto &elem : container) {
    if (first)
      first = false;
    else
      out << ", ";
    out << elem;
  }
  return out << "]";
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
  std::cout << v << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Which prints the 2d vector correctly

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

And does not mess with outputting strings. Is there a cleaner (concept-based?) way to write the template in C++20 or C++23?

Comment: Worth pointing out that while this may exclude `string` (which I'm not sure why you need to do), it also excludes a large amount of other ranges. Like `std::array`, `std::map`, `std::span`, ...

Comment: Well, `std::map` would require different code in any case because its `value_type` is a `std::pair`. But yes, lots of excluded containers for which this code is otherwise valid. For instance, does this even work for `std::vector`s with non-default allocators?

Comment: [p2286r8](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2286r8.html) is the better way :D

Comment: Generic template should involve at least one user type. Your version might conflict with possible future `operator<<` for std containers...

Comment: @Barry and Nathan Pierson Good points. What would be a better way to include containers like arrays and valarrays but exclude strings?

Comment: @Barry I would like strings to be printed the normal way without commas in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With concepts, you might require only container/range types and discard
string-like types, something like:

```
template <typename Container>
requires std::ranges::input_range<const Container>
     && (!std::convertible_to<const Container, std::string_view>)
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Container& container)
{
  out << "[";
  const char* sep = "";
  for (const auto &elem : container) {
    out << sep << elem;
    sep = ", ";
  }
  return out << "]";
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z4Y8hedYG)

With the caveats that generic template should involve at least one user type. Else it might conflict with possible future `operator<<` for std (or other library) containers...

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. It looks like it is possible to simplify the concept to ```template <std::ranges::input_range Container>
  requires (!std::convertible_to<const Container, std::string_view>)```. Is this correct, or will there be issues?

Comment: There are indeed several equivalent syntaxes. Choose your style. :-)

Answer (score 9):

The better way is to use `{fmt}`:

```cpp
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
  fmt::print("{}\n", v); // prints [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
}
```

With in C++23 will be available as `std::print`.

---

There are actually two issues with strings that you'd have to deal with:

- string literals (like `"["`) need to not be included
- strings (like actual `std::string`) need to not be included

You can get rid of both by rejecting anything convertible to `string_view` rather than requiring a specific shape of the container type like `C<T, A=?>` (which as I mentioned also eliminates things like `std::array`, `std::span`, and `std::map`). That would let you print `std::array` and `std::span` just fine, but then for `std::map` you have to deal with the problem of... how do you print `std::pair`? And then how do you print a `std::pair` where one of the elements is a range?

And then *where* do you put this operator overload? You can't put it in `std` (that's not allowed). But you also can't really put it *not* in `std`, since otherwise real code probably won't find it.

It's a complicated problem, which is why it's better to defer to a good library (like `{fmt}`) which handles this very well.

Comment: Thank you, Barry. I understand the namespace issue, but it is not a problem for me because I don't want it to go to production. It is mostly for personal use when I do "scripting" with C++. I was trying to avoid non-standard functions, so good to know fmt is coming to C++23. Unfortunately, even <format> isn't in gcc yet.

Answer (score 2):

You should not overload operators on types you don't own; you don't own std containers.  And you should only overload operators in associated namespaces; you are not allowed to inject overloads into the `std` namespace.

This means you shouldn't quite do what you are doing.

```
template<class T>
struct pretty_print {
  T&& t;
};
template<class T>
pretty_print(T&&)->pretty_print<T>;

template<typename T>
concept printable = requires(T t) {
  { std::declval<std::ostream&>() << t } -> std::same_as<std::ostream&>;
};
template<printable T>
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, pretty_print<T> pp ) {
  return os << pp.t;
}
```

this lets you do

```
void test1() {
  int x=42;
  std::cout << pretty_print{x} << "\n";
}
```

for any printable type `x`.  We are now, however, free to add overloads for non-printable types.

```
template<std::ranges::input_range T>
requires (not printable<T>)
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, pretty_print<T> pp ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  os << "[";
  for (auto&& e : pp.t | std::ranges::views::take(1))
  {
    os << pretty_print{e};
  }
  for (auto&& e : pp.t | std::ranges::views::drop(1))
  {
      os << ", ";
      os << pretty_print{e};
  }
  os << "]";
  return os;
}

void test2() {
  std::vector<int> v0 = {1,2,3};
  std::cout << pretty_print{v0} << "\n";
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> v1 = {{1},{1,2},{1,2,3}};
  std::cout << pretty_print{v1} << "\n";
}
```

Now if we want to support pairs:

```
template<typename T>
concept pairlike = requires(T t) {
  { t.first };
  { t.second };
};

template<pairlike P>
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, pretty_print<P> pp ) {
  os << "{ ";
  os << pretty_print{pp.t.first} << ", ";
  os << pretty_print{pp.t.second} << " }";
  return os;
}
```

and now maps work.

```
void test3() {
  std::map<int, int> m = {{0,1}, {1,2}, {2,4}};
  std::cout << pretty_print{m}  << "\n";
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/TbbxE15zT).

Answer (score 2):

Since C++23, the ISO C++ standard supports formatting ranges [P2286R8](https://wg21.link/P2286R8) and formatted output library `<print>` [P2093R14](https://wg21.link/P2093R14) [P2539R3](https://wg21.link/P2539R3), you can use `<format>` to do like this:

```cpp
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    std::cout << std::format("{}", v) << '\n';
}
```

Or even cleaner using `<print>`:

```cpp
#include <format>
#include <print>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    std::print("{}\n", v);
}
```

Clang gives the result as:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++23 -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp -o test && ./test
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```